# Running two MySQL servers that use the same data directory

Tags: mysql, dbms

## The situation

I have two MySQL instances, deployed on two different remote machines.
Both MySQL instances access the same data directory, which is stored on a persistent volume (this volume is provided by Gluster, but that's not really relevant, I'm only saying this for the sake of completeness).

I'm aware that it is strongly discouraged to run two MySQL servers using the same data directory, but it's not an impossible thing to do, as long as one takes the right precautions. In order to do this, I followed the steps suggested by the official documentation ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-data-directories.html ), more specifically in the paragraph named **Warning**. To sum it up:

- I'm using MySQL 5.6.
- I'm using MyISAM as default engine, as required.
- I specified log file names that are unique to each server.
- One server is going to be read-write, while the other server is going to be read-only.

So, I set everything up, I imported a test database and everything worked flawlessly. Both servers could read data from the same data directory.

## The problem

Now comes the problem. As soon as one server performs a write (by inserting a row into a table), the other server marks the table as corrupted for itself.
After looking into the problem for a while, I found out why this happened. Basically each server holds its own metadata describing each table. So, as soon as the first server updated a table, it also updated its own metadata, but it didn't update the metadata of the second server. As the second server checked the table, it noticed a mismatch between the current number of rows in the table and the number of rows it had previously saved in its metadata, therefore it marked the table as corrupted.
After some research, it turns out that the metadata is saved inside a default database named *information_schema*. At first, I thought of making the two server share the same *information_schema*, but this was nowhere to be found. As I later discovered, it's saved inside the memory of the program and there's no way you can manually update or access it.

## The questions

1. Since the documentation tells you exactly what precautions to take, I was expecting this to actually work...or else, what's the point of that guide in the official documentation? If this couldn't be done, why would it tell you how to do it in the first place?
2. Most importantly, do you know how to make this work, using MySQL?
3. If not, do you know of any other DBMSs that allow you to obtain this result (that is, running two servers that use the same data directory)?

Just keep in mind that I don't want to set up master-slave replication.
All other suggestions are welcome, thanks everyone for the help.

EDIT: I ended up not doing it, as everyone discouraged me from doing it. Thanks everyone for your input!

Comment: I'm working on a paper about data movement and data consistency. I have to propose several different scenarios and solutions to them. Then I have to do some benchmarking and show which one is the best. ( Obviously, I have already tested master-slave replication, that's why I said I don't want anyone to suggest it now).

Comment: It sounds like you need to enable [`external_locking`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_external-locking).  Check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Since the documentation tells you exactly what precautions to take, I was expecting this to actually work...or else, what's the point of that guide in the official documentation? If this couldn't be done, why would it tell you how to do it in the first place?

> 2. Most importantly, do you know how to make this work, using MySQL?

You said something that might have a bearing on the first two question

> Both MySQL instances access the same data directory, which is stored on a persistent volume (this volume is provided by Gluster, but that's not really relevant, I'm only saying this for the sake of completeness).

Interestingly, someone has claimed to have pulled this off.

On `Sep 24, 2010` (over a decade ago), [Richard Holloway answered a question he himself posted in Server Fault : `Can I run mysqld on top of glusterfs?`](https://serverfault.com/q/171166/69271)

Quoting Richard Holloway's answer

- Disable the query cache (Set query_cache_type=0, query_cache_size=0).
- Switch on external locking.
- [Richard cites MySQL 5.1 Doc on external locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/external-locking.html).
- [Michael - sqlbot just recommended 5.6 Doc in his comment.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215280/running-two-mysql-servers-that-use-the-same-data-directory#comment422205_215280).
- disable delays to writing.

This is a very daring answer ( [Godspeed, Spiderman !!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AglV2jLZ4qU) )

Just to throw in my 2 cents

- Do not use GlusterFS in async mode !!!
- Configure [skip-innodb](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-turning-off.html) on both mysqld instances.

> 3. If not, do you know of any other DBMSs that allow you to obtain this result (that is, running two servers that use the same data directory)?

The answer is Oracle RAC. It is designed to operate multiple Oracle instances sharing only one set of datafiles. Each instance has its own log buffer. Oh yeah, you will need boat loads of money (Oracle RAC is not open source).

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it.  MySQL is not designed to handle separate instances touching the same disk files.  Even if it is, I would not trust it since the developers are focused on other issues, such as optimization.

Optimization often depends on making more use of RAM and less use of disk.  Even if there is code for external locking, think of how much that would slow down queries!

What do you hope to gain?  If you are assuming that the server is more fragile than the network and disk drives, then consider Galera (well tested, popular, etc).  Group Replication will soon be a significant competitor to Galera; it is being heavily developed, pushed, and supported by Oracle.

MySQL is resilient to the crash of a server.  If you can salvage the disk(s) and attach them to a new CPU+etc, then essentially the "recovery from a power failure" can get you back to where you left off (less any uncommitted transactions).

Resilience from loss of a disk drive *used to* be the big worry.  Hence, RAID, DRBD, Replication, Galera, Group Replication, Aurora, etc.

It sounds like GlusterFS is competitor to NetApp.  Both are huge drives.  Feel free to put *two* instances of MySQL talking to *two* partitions of a GlusterFS; that's is often done with NetApp.

Back to server failure...  It is also OK to have *one* disk setup with *one* MySQL instance, plus the ability to fire up another instance against that same 'disk' in the event of a server failure.  Just don't have both instances running at the same time.